# Spring-Integration Filter when predicate is false within request-reply flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

I'm trying to use filter() in order to execute certain code conditionally and yet always return a reply in a request-reply flow.

For instance, in `Spring-Integration 5.5.17`, in the IntegrationFlow, I can conditionally multiply odd integer payloads by two.

```
    @Bean(name = "sendsEvenValuesWorksFlow")
    IntegrationFlow sendEvenValuesWorksFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sendsEvenValuesWorksChannel")
                               .filter("(payload % 2) == 1", filterSpec -> filterSpec.discardFlow(noop()))
                               .transform("payload * 2")
                               .get();
    }

    private static IntegrationFlow noop() {
        return f -> f.filter("true");
    }
```

where the filter has a `discardFlow` which does nothing.

But I would think that there would be a simpler way of continuing the flow with the current payload.  The following doesn't work, for instance, because it produces no output message:

```
    @Bean(name = "sendsEvenValuesFailsFlow")
    IntegrationFlow sendEvenValuesFailsFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sendsEvenValuesFailsChannel")
                               .filter("(payload % 2) == 1")
                               .transform("payload * 2")
                               .get();
    }
```

Is a `discard` mechanism (`flow` or `channel`) obligatory in order to guarantee a reply message is produced with a `filter()` method?  If so, is there a simpler way of creating a `noop()` flow?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you question is to just reply the same input payload, then your `noop` would look like this:

```
private static IntegrationFlow noop() {
    return f -> f.bridge();
}
```

The bridge is a simple pass-through request-reply handler, and if there is no output channel, it consults a `replyChannel` header.

Comment: Understood for ```f.bridge()``` and thanks for that.

The use of the ```discard``` argument is a bit counter-intuitive for me. I'm working if an option could be added to the filterEndpointSpec to force the return of the original message upon negative predicate.

Comment: Sorry, *wondering if an option can be added* ...

Comment: Well, no: that is not this endpoint responsibility. The filter can pass the message down or not. It is already up to target project to make more complex decision in a discard flow. That's you need a plain pass-through reply for your logic, but others might not. Therefore there is just general hook as a `discardChannel` or `discardFlow`. In your case it can be as simple as: `discardFlow(IntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted @artem-bilan's answer.  (Thanks very much.)

I wanted to build onto that answer with perhaps a shorter implementation:

```
    @Bean(name = "sendsEvenValuesWorksFlow")
    IntegrationFlow sendEvenValuesWorksFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sendsEvenValuesWorksChannel")
                               .filter("(payload % 2) == 1", discardReturnsCurrentMessage())
                               .transform("payload * 2")
                               .get();
    }

    public static Consumer<FilterEndpointSpec> discardReturnsCurrentMessage() {
        return filterSpec -> filterSpec.discardFlow(IntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge);
    }
```

The `discardReturnsCurrentMessage()` static method can be declared once and reused.  It also gives a precise definition of what is expected.